# Query when a type is created with CQLinq

Tags: c#, .net, ndepend, cqlinq

Let's say i have the follwoing code:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
}
public class MyImplementation : MyBase
{
}
public class MyService1
{
    MyImplementation myi = new MyImplementation();
}

public class MyService2
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        MyImplementation myi = new MyImplementation();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create a query with CQLinq that returns all places (or types) where a Class inherits from `MyBase` and is created somewhere with `new` ?

The query should return `MyService1` and `MyService2` or even better `MyService2.Foo()`

What i have so far:

```
from  x in Application.Types
where x.DeriveFrom("MyNamespace.MyBase")
select x
```